# Reset firewalld rules to default?

Tags: linux, centos, security, iptables, firewalld

On CentOS 7 have I been trying out different firewalld rules and iptables commands, and now want to do it all over, but only using firewalld.

**Question**

How can I reset all rules to the default that CentOS 7's firewalld ships with?

Answer (score 4):

Following piece of Code may be helpful for you.

`for srv in $(firewall-cmd --list-services);do firewall-cmd --remove-service=$srv; done
firewall-cmd --add-service={ssh,dhcpv6-client}
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`

Regards,

Ahmer Mansoor

Answer (score 4):

If you trully want to delete everything as John Ashpool say's

`rm -rf /etc/firewalld/zones` or /usr/etc/firewalld/zones depending on your distro

and

```
iptables -X
iptables -F
iptables -Z
```

plus

```
systemctl restart firewalld
```

and then you have a new set of rules and zones ;)

Comment: I had to also remove `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml` which was containing custom rules I added.

Comment: I did not knew that Tristan Thank you !

Comment: Works well on Fedora 38. Also had to modify NetworkManager managed connections which had firewalld zones left in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` via ` nmcli con mod myconnecttion connection.zone new-zone`. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

You may simply delete the files containing the customized zone rules from `/etc/firewalld/zones` (or `/usr/etc/firewalld/zones`, depending on the distribution). After that, reload `firewalld` with `firewall-cmd --complete-reload`, and it should start using the default settings. When you make changes to the zone rules, files will appear again in that directory.

As for `iptables`, you may reset all rules with `iptables -F`. Rebooting works as well, unless you implemented some sort of persistency. Beware that `firewalld` may be configured to use `iptables` as its backend, which means it will add or remove `iptables` rules itself, according to what you specified in its zone rules.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just remove all the services and rules from all the zones you have edited. Except for SSH in case you are working on a remote server. That is easy: `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=WHATEVER --remove-service=WHATEVER`

And after all have been removed, just `sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`

HOWEVER: If you haven't saved the firewall rules, then just restart with `systemctl restart firewalld`

I don't think there is any reset function in it.

Comment: This will not remove the manual iptables rules I have made.

Comment: Then you want to reset iptables, not firewall. https://kerneltalks.com/virtualization/how-to-reset-iptables-to-default-settings/

Answer (score 1):

Any default `zones` that come with distribution, if modified, get copied to `/etc/firewalld/zones` directory with those modifications.

Which also means that the source of `default` zone files is not this directory and re-installation doesn't know about the files under this directory (`/etc/firewalld/zones`) so these files will be `untouched` by reinstallation. Unless these files are removed, firewalld continues to load your modifications from this directory.

You can backup and delete all those files (safely) from `/etc/firewalld/zones` and restart  firewalld which then comes back to default distribution installed zone configurations.

> It is safe in a sense that, the default distribution zone
>   configurations allow SSH by default. However, if you logged into this
>   server via a different port of SSH than 22 or by any other means than
>   SSH, then you need to be careful, removing all those files from
>   `/etc/firewalld/zones`

```
sudo cp -pR /etc/firewalld/zones /etc/firewalld/zones.bak
sudo rm -f /etc/firewalld/zones/*
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

In case any other config files are modified, the firewalld itself can be reinstalled, however, the firewalld RPM needs to be downloaded to reinstall it.

Install `yum-downloadonly` plugin:

```
(RHEL5)
# yum install yum-downloadonly
(RHEL6, RHEL7)
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Before using the plugin, check `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/downloadonly.conf` to confirm that this plugin is `enabled=1`

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp firewalld
# rpm -ivh --force /tmp/firewalld*.rpm
```

> BTW `yum reinstall firewalld` doesn't replace the modified config
>   files.